# WPF : GridViewColumn.Header drag (reorder) problem

Tags: wpf, gridview, drag

In my WPF Application I have an GridViewColumn that looks like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="170">

    <GridViewColumn.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Path Data="{StaticResource pathStar}" Fill="Gold" Stroke="Red"/>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">New items</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </GridViewColumn.Header>
    ...
```

I am unable to drag/reorder the column if I click and drag on any of the subobjects like the path or the textblock. Only if I click on the free space I am able to drag this column.

How will I make the whole column drag able again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting `IsHitTestVisible="false"` on your StackPanel, Path and Textblock.

Comment: Great! Thanks - Works perfect and it's so easy.